# Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. working on remote windows .net

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, ado.net

I am working with C# windows application, need to connect MS SQL server and use SPs.
But I'm getting "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding." error. This error getting on remote system's application. I already specified "command.CommandTimeout = 0;" and Timer is set to 5000; I need to run query / SPs for scheduled time. command is SqlCommand Object. But getting the same.

Please help any one!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show us some code including the way you set the timeout and you call the stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

First you have to check manually if you can get connected to your database with SQLServer Management Studio If Yes then you have to set :

```
command.CommandTimeout = 60;
```

Good Luck!